# How to get data using foreach eloquent

Tags: laravel, foreach, eloquent

I have a problem to get data using forach eloquent in laravel 6.

To get value which I want to use in foreach

```
        $array_suspect_idBLE = Transaction::
            select('id_ble')
            ->where('id_user',$suspect_id)
            ->where('updated_at','>=',$suspect_in)
            ->where('updated_at','<=',$suspect_out)
            ->pluck('id_ble');
```

The output

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#281
  #items: array:5 [
    0 => 18
    1 => 6
    2 => 12
    3 => 16
    4 => 10
  ]
}
```

and the foreach

```
foreach($array_suspect_idBLE as $arr){
            
            $suspect_list = Transaction::
                select('id_transaction','id_user','id_ble')
                ->where('id_user','<>',$suspect_id)
                ->where('updated_at','>=',$suspect_in)
                ->where('updated_at','<=',$suspect_out)
                ->where('id_ble', $arr->array_suspect_idBLE)
                ->get();
        }
```

And the error is

message: Trying to get property 'array_suspect_idBLE' of non-object

The expected result are all id_transaction, id_user, id_ble that connect to array_suspect_idBLE 18,6,12,16,10

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: you don't have an object you have what ever value is in that field on the table

Comment: If you pluck the column, as a result you have a list of ids. In your suspect_list query use just `$arr` instead of `$arr->array_suspect_idBLE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `pluck()` method returns an array of values. You are treating it as if it returns a collection of objects.

The solution would be to change it into this:

```php
foreach($array_suspect_idBLE as $value) {
    $suspect_list = Transaction::
        select('id_transaction','id_user','id_ble')
        ->where('id_user','<>',$suspect_id)
        ->where('updated_at','>=',$suspect_in)
        ->where('updated_at','<=',$suspect_out)
        ->where('id_ble', $value)
        ->get();
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. the result was correct but not showing all data. I think because of replace every iteration. The data only show which connect to array_suspect_idBLE = 10. How about the first array like 18,6,12,16